# how do i concatenate input values and convert them to an overall number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 buttons with values 1 - 4, I want to concatenate the button value each time a number is clicked and present this in `#result` but I'm getting confused by how this should be done. At the moment I have created an array and then pushed each value into the array as it is clicked then going onto convert this to a string which I will then convert to a number but I'm guessing this is the totally wrong approach, can anyone advise how I can achieve this?

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var arr = [], value;

  $('.num').on('click', function(e) {
    value = $(this).val();
    arr.push(value);
    var test = parseInt(arr.toString());
    console.log(test);
    $('#result').text(test);


  });

});
```

HTML

```
 <form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" id="result" />
    <input type="button" class="num" value="1" />
    <input type="button" class="num" value="2" />
    <input type="button" class="num" value="3" />
    <input type="button" class="num" value="4" />
  </form>
```

JSBIN  - http://jsbin.com/exuwuz/2/edit

So basically hit 1 and #result will show 1 hit 2 and #result will show 12 etc etc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to concatenate two numbers in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723716/how-to-concatenate-two-numbers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can be simplified. Try:

```
$('input.num').click(
   function() {
    $('#result')[0].value += this.value;
   }
);​
```

see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/axnWy/)

Comment: To retrieve the raw (unwrapped) input element.

Answer (score 1):

Use `""` in concatenation to prevent the numbers from adding:

```
$(this).val("" + $(this).val() + value);
```

Answer (score 1):

`array.toString()` returns comma separated list of values of the array (eg. `1,2,3,4`). `parseInt` will then parse only the first value (first part of the string which is a correct integer).

To achive the behaviour you want use [`array.join()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) instead of `array.toString()`, which will just concatenate the content of the array:

```
var test = parseInt(arr.join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about concatenate and display it directly?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.num').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#result').val("" + $('#result').val() + $(this).val());
  });
});
```

Comment: That would add them as numbers.

Comment: It doesn't add them as numbers - tested in Google Chrome. But I decided to add "" just to make sure.