# alerts that concatenate rather than add

Tags: javascript, alert

super remedial question that I just cant quite figure out (new to javascript). 
I need to find a way to prompt for a string of text and then alert that string of text 3 times. I have tried the + sign in my alert but that would give me NaN or just an addition rather than just the string. For example if I input 2 it would return 6 rather than 222 which I need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to concatenate two numbers in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723716/how-to-concatenate-two-numbers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to include strings in your concatenation:

```
alert(num+''+num+''+num);
```

Another is to convert the number to a string first:

```
var str = num.toString();
alert(str+str+str);
```

The whole thing would be:

```
var num = +prompt("Enter a number");
var str = num.toString();
alert(str + str + str);
```

Comment: var x = +prompt("Enter a string of text");
var x= num.toString();
alert(str+str+str);

Comment: thats what I have right now but now its not even alerting NaN, or anything else for that matter

Comment: The first line should be `var num`, not `var x`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity; what does the leading `+` do before `prompt`?

Comment: `prompt` returns a string. Putting `+` before it converts it to a number.

Comment: this was my issue, it was in the + before the prompt. problem is now sovled

Answer (score 1):

Just include a string somewhere in between:

```
2+''+2+2
```

E.g.

```
var input = prompt('type something'), result = '';

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    result += input;

console.log(result);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/35tp3/

Comment: var x = +prompt("Enter a string of text");
alert(x+''+x+''+x)          this works for numbers but when i input text characters it does not work

Comment: @user3432271 Test the fiddle please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var number = 2, repeat = 3;
Array(repeat+1).join( number );
```

That will output "222"

If you want to add a space:

```
Array(repeat+1).join(" " + number).trim();
```

Which will output "2 2 2"