# Can there be an efficient way for the dual loops?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, algorithm, loops

I got a question in exam where I was given an array `a`

```js
a = [9,8,10,2]
```

what I need to do is cross iterate the array on itself and get the concatenation of all the possible elements i.e `a*a`

Once all elements are concatenated in that order, then I need to sum them up. My code is in the snippet:

Also tried in PHP

```php
function sumIt($a) {
  $totalSum = 0;
  $len1 = count($a);
  for($i = 0; $i < $len1; $i++){
    for($ii = 0; $ii < $len1; $ii++) {
      $totalSum += $a[$i].''.$a[$ii];
    }
  }
  return $totalSum;
}
```

The input array `a` can have the following value constraints:

1. The length of array can be at max 10^5
2. Value of individual item can be unto 10^6

My code works fine mostly, but on higher end values for array `a` I start getting time exceed errors which is **MAX 4 seconds**. I tried with `while` & `foreach` loops with no effect. As the code is quite simple, I was wondering if anyone can provide hints on increasing the performance and reducing the execution time.

PS: I tried the --i thing in for loop as well if anyone knows, no difference in that regard as well.

```js
a = [10, 23, 4857, 3, 49, 293, 1, 394,85, 392, 484, 392, 30, 4849,48, 20, 3948, 2493, 84, 3492, 384,92, 384,38, 49, 45, 489, 53,40,9875, 84,9,572,3958, 346,456,45, 56,4564, 6,7867,8, 78,9789, 234,234, 435,34,6, 45,345, 4564,5, 657,45, 45, 345, 667, 5,6756, 877,68, 6765,4, 34, 6, 54, 3, 654, 6, 5, 8776, 43, 32, 67, 89, 876,543,2,34,5, 654, 35, 6, 4, 345, 678, 9, 8, 765, 467,878,9, 4352, 5, 6743, 4, 47, 57,65, 345, 78, 765, 645,63, 56, 5786, 676, 4564,5, 42, 46, 786, 97, 896,567,86, 3777, 65, 6, 877, 65, 67, 2039757584,5348];

function sumIt(a) {
  totalSum = 0;
  const len1 = a.length;
  for(let i = 0; i < len1; i++){
    for(let ii = 0; ii < len1; ii++) {
      totalSum += +(a[i]+''+a[ii]);
    }
  }
  return totalSum;
}

currentTime = new Date().getTime();
console.log(sumIt(a));
console.log(new Date().getTime() - currentTime);


function sumIt2(a) {
  totalSum = 0;
  const len1 = a.length;
  for(let i = 0; i < len1; i++){
    first = Math.pow(10, Math.ceil(Math.log(a[i] + 1)));
    for(let j = 0; j < len1; j++) {
     totalSum += (first + a[j])
    }
  }
  return totalSum;
}

currentTime = new Date().getTime();
console.log(sumIt2(a));
console.log(new Date().getTime() - currentTime);
```

Comment: `+(a[i]+''+a[ii])` is very inefficient. Anything to do with strings is always an expensive operation. Try to think of a way that you can do this without having to use strings. Also, your loop is `O(n^2)` but off the top of my head, I can't think of a way around that. (Your problem seems fundamentally `O(n^2)`, though happy to be corrected.)

Comment: I didn't vote you down, but I'm considering it because you have failed to ask the exam question they actually asked you. What is the actual question? By the way `.` is String concatenation in PHP.

Comment: A little bit less operations: once you have `i` and `ii` you can add both `i`, `ii` and `ii`,`i.`.

Comment: perhaps start the inner iteration at the index of the outer, and as @PM77-1 said, record i,ii and ii,i

Comment: @StackSlave question mentioned in the start, array is given which need to have all of it's elemnts cross concatenated with itself and then added mathematically

Comment: @SumnerEvans is there any other way to concatenate integers and then convert back to number? I assumed .toString() is more expensive that's why added with string

Comment: Note that each number in the array will be on the right side of a concatenation, and on the left side. The right side contribution is just the sum of the array. The left side contribution is a little trickier. For the example, the answer is `9+8+10+2 + 90+80+20 + 2*9+2*8+2*2`. That's O(N*d) where `d` is the number of unique digit counts in the array.

Comment: @PM77-1 yes but then how do I know when that ii+i is already done when I reach i==ii

Comment: @user3386109 now that's an interesting direction I will like to dig more on

Comment: Numeric-only equivalent for the concatenation is `a[i] * Math.pow(10, Math.ceil(Math.log(a[ii] + 1))) + a[ii]`. Not convinced even that is quick enough to calculate up to 10^10 sums in 4 seconds.

Comment: @Phylogenesis the equation is faster the concatenation, however returned results are not same in the snippet above;

Comment: @PaulRooney updated the function answer still having differences. I assume what I need is `(a[i]*((a[i].len+a[j].len)-1))+a[j]` however getting the length of integer needs conversion to string, is there a way to know that?

Comment: There is https://stackoverflow.com/a/43826883/1540468 which may help.

Comment: Those are not all of the permutations.

Answer (score 2):

The following algorithm (based on @user3386109's idea) is way quicker:

```js
// Generate random array
let a = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  a.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1e6));
}

function sumIt(a) {
  totalSum = 0;
  const len1 = a.length;
  for(let i = 0; i < len1; i++){
    for(let ii = 0; ii < len1; ii++) {
      totalSum += +(a[i]+''+a[ii]);
    }
  }
  return totalSum;
}

function sumIt2(a) {
  let total = 0;
  let aLen = a.length;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < aLen; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < aLen; j++) {
        var subtotal = a[i] * Math.pow(10, Math.ceil(Math.log10(a[j] + 1))) + a[j];
        total += subtotal;
    }
  }
  
  return total;
}

function sumIt3(a) {
  let subtotal    = 0;
  let multiplier  = 0;
  let digitCounts = [a.length, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    subtotal += a[i];
    digitCounts[Math.ceil(Math.log10(a[i] + 1))]++;
  }
  
  for (let i = 0; i < digitCounts.length; i++) {
    multiplier += Math.pow(10, i) * digitCounts[i];
  }
  
  return subtotal * multiplier;
}

console.clear();

performance.mark("start");
console.log(sumIt(a));
performance.mark("sumIt");
console.log(sumIt2(a));
performance.mark("sumIt2");
console.log(sumIt3(a));
performance.mark("sumIt3");

performance.measure("sumIt",  "start",  "sumIt");
performance.measure("sumIt2", "sumIt",  "sumIt2");
performance.measure("sumIt3", "sumIt2", "sumIt3");

console.log(performance.getEntriesByType("measure").map(p => p.duration));
```

However, with larger array sizes (above about 140), the results start to diverge. I think that is more to do with the precision of JS's `Number` type rather than an underlying problem in the algorithm.