# Javascript Calculator adding digits

Tags: javascript

```
let numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]')
 let display = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]')
 display.innerHTML = '';
 
 
numberButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(button.innerHTML);
   display.innerHTML = button.innerHTML;
})
```

how do I make the code as such that when I click a button once and then do it again, it returns me 33 instead of just 3. Explanations are appreciated

Comment: Add HTML so that we can understand it better...

Comment: Does this answer works for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/1723724/11024771

Comment: Change it to ```display.innerHTML += button.innerHTML;``` you can use ```+=``` instead. It is equal to ```display.innerHTML = display.innerHTML + button.innerHTML;```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to handle this:

```
let numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]')
 let display = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]')
 display.innerHTML = '';
 
 
numberButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    display.innerText = display.innerText + button.innerText
    console.log(button.innerHTML)
})
```

Comment: @J_SIRTHIK, please see my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```js
const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]')
const display = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]')
 display.innerHTML = '';
 
 
numberButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.target.innerHTML += e.target.innerHTMl;
})
```

Explanations:
e.target gives you a reference to an instance of just clicked btn, and inner HTMl - I thinkyou already know what it is - gives you text inside button tag. And += is how I call it "lazy incrementation" operator! it will do the actions like these: let i = 9; i+=2 // === i = i + 2

Answer (score 0):

Store the no of times the button is clicked in a variable say 'count'.

```
'3'.repeat(count)
```

The above code repeats the string 3 'count' no of times.

If you have multiple buttons I suggest saving the count in an array